# Async Queue implementation .Wait() faster than await

Tags: c#, async-await, producer-consumer

To provide producer-consumer functionality that can queue and execute **async** methods one after the other, I'm trying to implement an async queue. I noticed major performance issues using it in a large application.

```
async Task Loop() {
     while (Verify()) {
         if (!_blockingCollection.TryTake(out var func, 1000, _token)) continue;
         await func.Invoke();       
     }
}
```

Implementation of AsyncQueue.Add:

```
public void Add(Func<Task> func) {
    _blockingCollection.Add(func);
}
```

Example usage from arbitrary thread:

```
controller.OnEvent += (o, a) => _queue.Add(async (t) => await handle(a));
```

Execution paths' depend on the state of the application and include

- async network requests that internally use TaskCompletionSource to return result
- IO operations
- tasks that get added to a list and are awaited using Task.WhenAll(...)
- an async void method that converts an array and awaits a network request

Symptoms:
The application slows down gradually.

When I replace `await func.Invoke()` with `func.Invoke().Wait()` instead of awaiting it properly, performance improves dramatically and it does not slow down.

Why is that? Is an async queue that uses `BlockingCollection` a bad idea?

What is a better alternative?

Comment: I don't think that issue is with blocking collection. What actually your `func` does?

Comment: That loop is flawed anyway -- if there are no items to consume it's going to spin, which is going to drive up your CPU usage. That's going to dominate any CPU usage from anywhere else. Use `BlockingCollection.Take` instead, which sleeps the thread until an item is available.

Comment: What thread calls into `Loop()`? Is it a threadpool thread? Or something else?

Comment: How does your setup look like? 
1 producer - 1 consumer?  
n producers - 1 consumer?  
1 producer - n consumers?   
or n producers - m consumers?

Comment: @canton7 Loop is called from a threadpool thread: `Task.Run(Loop)`

Comment: What does "performance issues" mean? CPU usage? Thread pool exhaustion? Items from the queue not being processed "quickly enough"?

Comment: @PeterCsala There are n producers, the only consumer is is the `Loop` method that executes the functions that the producers have added.

Comment: @Manual Can you please share with us the producer side as well?

Comment: The performance issue I'm seeing is that the executed methods gradually get slower. The specifics are hard to pin down as there are async api calls. What surprises me is that when I use .Wait() the overall execution is about 100 times faster.

Comment: @PeterCsala I added the producer side to the question.

Comment: @Manuel For inspiration you can check [my sample codes](https://github.com/peter-csala/parallel-programming-dotnet#low-level-abstractions-) where I use `BlockingCollection` in several ways to implement throttled producer-consumer pattern.

Comment: Can you include in your question an example of how you call the `Add` method from the producer side?

Comment: I have added an example of a call site.

Comment: Can you also include the code of the `handle` method? What we really want to see is the "meat" of the function that runs so much faster when `Wait`ed than `await`ed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is that?

There isn't enough information in the question to provide an answer to this.

As others have noted, there's a CPU-consuming spin issue with the loop as it currently is.

In the meantime, I can at least answer this part:

> Is an async Queue that uses BlockingCollection a bad idea?

Yes.

> What is a better alternative?

Use an async-compatible queue. E.g., `Channels`, or `BufferBlock`/`ActionBlock` from TPL Dataflow.

Example using Channels:

```
async Task Loop() {
  await foreach (var func in channelReader.ReadAllAsync()) {
    await func.Invoke();
  }
}
```

or if you're not on .NET Core yet:

```
async Task Loop() {
  while (await channelReader.WaitToReadAsync()) {
    while (channelReader.TryRead(out var func)) {
      await func.Invoke();
    }
  }
}
```